# How do I wrap text in a jTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I'm currently using a jTextArea, and that has a setLineWrap() method to indicate whether text should be wrapped or not. Do jTextPanes have an equivalent to this? I know it can wrap words, but I need it to wrap characters.

For example, "oooooooooooo..." should be wrapped and displayed as two or more lines of o's instead of one long line with a scroll bar. So is this possible with jTextPanes?

Comment: Did you check [this question][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036543/how-is-word-wrapping-implemented-in-jtextpane-and-how-do-i-make-it-wrap-a-strin]?  The link is off-site, but it appears to be related to the editorkit that's used for it.

Answer (score 0):

JTextPanes word wrap automatically, you have to set the size.

```
jTextPane.setSize(someValue);
```

The size should be set to something small.

But this doesn't help you because it doesn't do that with characters... Try using <br> maybe? Or check this link: http://java-sl.com/wrap.html

Comment: It seems the Website http://java-sl.com is offline (anyone knows what happened to that site?) I found a archived version at archive.org - http://web.archive.org/web/20220203131713/http://java-sl.com/wrap.html